# My QWebEngineView class doesen't display in my Windows

Tags: python, pyqt5

I would like to insert in the two boxes I created "box_url" and "box_info" two instances of my "WebPage" class, the problem that I have tried several times but I can not see them, without using a "QGridLayout" becasu with use it I think works, I would like to understand how to do thanks, here is the code,
`

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog,QApplication
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineSettings, QWebEngineView
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl

class WebPage(QWebEngineView):

    def load(self, url):
        self.setUrl(QUrl(url))

    def adjustTitle(self):
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title())

    def disableJS(self):
        settings = QWebEngineSettings.globalSettings()
        settings.setAttribute(QWebEngineSettings.JavascriptEnabled, False)

class Page(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Page, self).__init__()
        self.setObjectName("self")
        self.resize(582, 437)
        self.label_info = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.label_info.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 20, 47, 13))
        self.label_info.setObjectName("label_info")

        self.box_info = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(self)
        self.box_info.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 50, 231, 161))
        self.box_info.setObjectName("box_info")

        self.web = WebPage()
        self.web.load("https://i.picsum.photos/id/0/200/300.jpg?hmac=0pq7Zy79Vy4K-8w1qAMo1ppYmPvl-7lvwSx-LyZ7vNY")
        self.web.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 50, 231, 161))
        self.web.setObjectName("url1")

     
        self.box_url = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(self)
        self.box_url.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 230, 491, 151))
        self.box_url.setObjectName("box_url")

        self.web1 = WebPage()
        self.web1.load("https://i.picsum.photos/id/0/200/300.jpg?hmac=0pq7Zy79Vy4K-8w1qAMo1ppYmPvl-7lvwSx-LyZ7vNY")
        self.web1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 50, 231, 161))
        self.web1.setObjectName("url2")


     
        self.button_close = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.button_close.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(250, 400, 75, 23))
        self.button_close.setObjectName("button_close")


        self.retranslateUi(Page)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(self)
       

    def retranslateUi(self, Page):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        self.setWindowTitle(_translate("Page", "Form"))
        self.label_info.setText(_translate("Page", "<html><head/><body><p><span style=\" font-size:10pt; font-weight:600;\">Info:</span></p></body></html>"))
        self.button_close.setText(_translate("Page", "Close"))
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    page = Page()
    page.show()
    app.exec_()
```

`
I would like to get this
Image:
[image]

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: @eyllanesc i provide

Answer (score 0):

For a widget to be shown as part of another widget then it must be a child of the widget or of some child. Also if a layout is set to a widget then all the widgets added to the layout will be children of the initial widget. So your code works with the QGridLayout for the latter. So if you don't want to use a layout then pass it as a parent to the window:

```
self.web = WebPage(self)
# ...
self.web1 = WebPage(self)
# ...
```

Although in this case it is better to use the layout that you establish in the boxes and add the Pages as children:

```
self.web = WebPage()
self.web.load(
    "https://i.picsum.photos/id/0/200/300.jpg?hmac=0pq7Zy79Vy4K-8w1qAMo1ppYmPvl-7lvwSx-LyZ7vNY"
)
lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.box_info)
lay.addWidget(self.web)
self.web.setObjectName("url1")

self.box_url = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(self)
self.box_url.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 230, 491, 151))
self.box_url.setObjectName("box_url")

self.web1 = WebPage()
self.web1.load(
    "https://i.picsum.photos/id/0/200/300.jpg?hmac=0pq7Zy79Vy4K-8w1qAMo1ppYmPvl-7lvwSx-LyZ7vNY"
)
lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.box_url)
lay.addWidget(self.web1)
self.web1.setObjectName("url2")
```

Comment: @dantix93 then please review the [tour]